# unable to plot the data

Tags: matlab, plot

I have written the following matlab function

```
function [t x] = MSD(xo, z, fo, c)
T = 1/fo; t = 0:T/10:10*T; fd = fo * sqrt(1-z*z);
wo = 2*pi*fo; w1 = wo * z; wd = 2*pi * fd;
x = xo * exp(-w1*t) .* cos(wd*t);
grid on;
plot(t,x,c); 

xlabel('time [s]'); 
ylabel('displacement');
s = sprintf('unforced Mass-Spring Damper [damped freq: %.3f Hz]', fd); title(s);
end
```

and when i run it, the following errors appear in the command window:

```
MSD(.1, .7,.4, .2)
??? Error using ==> plot
Data must be a single matrix Y or a list of pairs X,Y

Error in ==> MSD at 13
plot(t,x,c);
```

Comment: What are you trying to use `c` for?

Comment: c is a constant and i want to plot it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thus your call should be

```
 plot(t,x,t,c*ones(1,length(t)));
```

which, simplifying, is equivalent to:

```
 plot(t,x);
 hold on

 c_vect = c * ones(1, length(t));  //you need a vector (constant in this case) 
                                   //to be plotted against t!!
                                   //ones(1, length(t)) will give you
                                   //[1111 ... 1] (as many ones as 
                                   //the entries of t)
 plot(t,c_vect);
```

Comment: i just want toplot 3 values in your suggested answer you considered 4 values. also would u mind explaining why should i use the way u suggested i find difficulty to understand it

Comment: what plot cares about are arrays, that's it. this means that `plot(t,x)` produces a plot of segments whose extrema are the points `[t(i),x(i)]` - `[t(i+1),x(i+1)]`. Therefore, if you need to plot a constant value you should call `plot(t,vector of constant values equal to c having same dimension of t)`.

Comment: moreover, when you do `plot(t1,x1,t2,x2)` you will produce two curves following the same rules I wrote above.

Comment: but what if i used the following:c_vect = c * ones(1, length(x));

Comment: @Amr it's the same..you need a vector as large as either `t` or `x`

Comment: @amr indeed it's the same because `plot(t,x)` works as long as `t` and `x` have same dimension.

Answer (score 5):

Acorbe's answer is correct, but it doesn't explain *why*.

In short, you can use the [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) command to either plot a vector `x` against a vector `y`, like so:

```
plot(x, y)
```

or plot several graphs on the same axes (vector `x1` against `y1`, vector `x2` against `y2`, and so on...), for instance:

```
plot(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, ...)
```

The latter syntax demands the number of input vectors to be **even**, because it plots them by **pairs**.

I believe that you want to show `c` as a line that intersects with the `x(t)` graph. For this you need to create a new function `y(t) = c` so that you can plot it:

```
y = c * ones(size(t));  % # Or c * ones(1, length(t)) like Acorbe has shown
```

This simply creates a vector with the same size of t, where each element equals to `c`. Only then you can plot it on the same axes as `x(t)`, like so:

```
plot(t, x, t, y)
```

or in a shorter form:

```
plot(t, x, t, c * ones(size(t)))
```

Hope that clears things up!

Comment: your explaination is appreciated

Comment: @EitanT  That's interesting. The documentiation (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) suggests that when typing (x,y1,y2,y3), the vecors y1,y2,y3 are plotted against x. In that case an even number of arguments wouldn't be requierd. Does that mean that the documentation is incorrect, or did I just misread it?

Comment: @Konstantin you misread it. The syntax is pairs of vectors (xn, yn).

Comment: @EitanT You are right. I could swear it was different when I checked it :D Maybe I should delete my comment?